How to remove clock symbol in input type time in html
I need to hide clock icon in input type html. with reference
  <input id="appt-time" type="time" name="appt-time" min="12:00" max="18:00" class='time'/>

input[type="time"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    background: none;
}

this one working fine. Clock symbol is not showing. but i need that class to target that input.
.time input[type="time"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    background: none;
}

This one not working, still i'm able to see the icon.

.time input[type="time"] would select a time input field, that was a descendant of an element with the class time. input[type="time"].time::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator (if you really need to be that specific, and using just the class is not enough already.)

Your selector is for an input as a child of .time.
You need to select the .time element's indicator


.time::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  background: none;
}
<input id="appt-time" type="time" name="appt-time" min="12:00" max="18:00" class='time' />




This targets an input within (or as a descendant of) an element with class time:
.time input[type="time"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator

If the class is on the input itself then you wouldn't want a space between them.  Perhaps something like this:


input.time[type="time"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    background: none;
}
<input id="appt-time" type="time" name="appt-time" min="12:00" max="18:00" class='time'/>



